# primary index on column having duplicates

Tags: index

must primary index be done over the primary key column?
can the primary index be done on a column having duplicates?

I searched the textbook but I found it not that clear?

Comment: What's "primary index", if not primary key?

Comment: Which database system(s) does your textbook generally reference/ are you learning about?...as that'll affect the answer potentially. If by primary index you mean the clustered index, then in some database systems, it doesn't have to be clustered on the primary key and therefore doesn't need to be unique but again that would depend on the database system being discussed.